# Could someone de-sugar this monad transform snippet?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Written in this handy do-notation, this seems pretty clear to me.  But I can't seem to get the de-sugared version using `>>=` to work which is worrisom. Could someone re-write these in expanded notation please?

Not nested

```
stack1 :: StateT Int Identity ( Int, Int )
stack1 = do
    a <- get 
    put ( a + 1 )
    b <- get
    return ( a, b )

runstack1 :: ( Int, Int )
runstack1 = evalState stack1 11
```

Nested

```
stack3 :: StateT Int ( StateT String ( StateT String Identity ) ) ( Int, String, String )
stack3 = do
    modify (+10)
    lift $ modify ( ++ " world" )
    lift . lift $ modify ( ++ " word" )
    a <- get
    b <- lift get
    c <- lift . lift $ get
    return ( a, b, c )


runStack3 :: ( Int, String, String )
runStack3 = runIdentity $ evalStateT ( evalStateT ( evalStateT runStack3 1 ) "hello" ) "harro"
```

Additionally, by comparing at the signature of runStack1 and runStack3 I can see why `runIdentity` is needed, but could someone explain the internals of why this is, since both stack1 and stack3 are wrapping Identity constructor?

Comment: Nested StateT is pretty weird. Why not define a single level StateT?

Comment: @DonStewart woa you wrote real world Haskell! But yeah I fixed the question so there's a more logical progression now. P.S., I'm having trouble with single stack StateT as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desugared version of the nested example:

```
stack4 :: StateT Int ( StateT String ( StateT String Identity ) ) ( Int, String, String )
stack4 = modify (+10) >>= \_ ->
         (lift $ modify ( ++ " world" )) >>= \_ ->
         (lift . lift $ modify ( ++ " word" )) >>= \_ ->
         get >>= \a ->
         lift get >>= \b -> 
         (lift . lift $ get) >>= \c ->
         return (a,b,c)
```

In applicative style:

```
import Control.Applicative

stack5 :: StateT Int ( StateT String ( StateT String Identity ) ) ( Int, String, String )
stack5 = modify (+10) *> 
         (lift $ modify ( ++ " world" )) *>
         (lift . lift $ modify ( ++ " word" )) *>  
         ((,,) <$> get <*> lift get <*> (lift . lift $ get))
```

Also, Lambdabot can perform automatic desugaring, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019670/desugaring-do-notation-for-monads).

As for the need for `runIdentity`, there's nothing mysterious about that. You have to unwrap every layer of a monad stack to get to the value inside, and `Identity` happens to be in the stack. Now, the `State` monad can be implemented in terms of `StateT` and `Identity`, but in that case the user is presented an "unified view" which hides the inner machinery. If you check the source code for `runState` in the `transformers` package, you'll see that it calls `runIdentity` internally.