# Haskell monads and the do statement

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm new to monads and its use and the following structure using the do-statement had me quite confused:

```
pairs xs ys = do x <- xs
                 y <- ys
                 return (x, y)
```

I was told this should return all possible pairs of x and y, which I do not understand because I was earlier taught that the following code:

```
eval (Val n) = Just n
eval (Div x y) = do n <- eval x
                    m <- eval y
                    safediv n m
```

means: execute `eval x`, then keep its result if not equal to `Nothing` (otherwise return Nothing) as `n`, then the same for `eval y`, and then if both are not `Nothing` it will proceed to the final function `safediv` that combines both results (and otherwise return `Nothing` too).

However the 1st use of the do-statement in the function `pairs` works totally different?

If someone could help me out on this and explain what's the actually proper functionality of the do-statement and its structure, it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: the reason for this is that the do-notation is just *syntactic sugar* for `>>=`, and as you have two total different `>>=` here you get this different behaviour and different descriptions of what's going on. I think I remember your question and I think I even did the `do` as an alternative version for your question with `>>=`

Comment: There is already a question/anser here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019670/desugaring-do-notation-for-monads

Comment: also have a look at this: http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads - I don't think we could explain it any better (or with nicer pictures) ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig LYAH's pictures are very nice, but I see them and raise with the pictures at http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: @chi ... well check mate ... or almost as this only has a very spare lines on the do notation :D

Comment: Al[.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PunctuatedForEmphasis) Ways. Use. Type. Signatures!

Comment: Thanks for the link to (what looks like) a clear explanation on monads in general, should come useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `do` construct works in **any** monad, and there you are using it in two different monads.

In the first case,

```
pairs xs ys = do x <- xs
                 y <- ys
                 return (x, y)
```

you are working in the list monad, i.e. `[]`. You can see that because you use `x <- xs` and `xs` is of type `[something]`.

In the second case

```
eval (Val n) = Just n
eval (Div x y) = do n <- eval x
                    m <- eval y
                    safediv n m
```

you are working in the `Maybe` monad. Indeed, you use `y <- eval x` and `eval` returns `Maybe something`.

Each monad defines its own rules about what `<-` should mean. In the list monad, it roughly means "consider all possible elements", in the Maybe one "take the `x` in `Just x`, and fail otherwise".

Technically, the `<-` construct within a `do` is desugared into a call to the `>>=` operator, which every monad defines independently.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the different functionalities of <- for different types of monads, I got it now.