# Does the main-function in Haskell always start with main = do?

Tags: haskell, program-entry-point, do-notation

In java we always write:

```
public static void main(String[] args){...}
```

when we want to start writing a program.

**My question is, is it the same for Haskell, IE: can I always be sure to declare:
main = do, when I want to write code for a program in Haskell?**

for example:

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "What's your name?"  
    name <- getLine 
    putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name)
```

This program is going to ask the user "What's your name?"
the user input will then be stored inside of the name-variable, and
"Hello" ++ name will be displayed before the program terminates.

Comment: `main` - yes. But `do` is a part of the body, which may or may not be there. See [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/2-my-first-program#the-main-function)

Comment: `main = putStrLn "It depends on how large 'main' is."`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer**: **No**, we have to declare a `main =`, but *not* a `do`.

The **`main` must be an *IO monad* type** (so `IO a`) where `a` is arbitrary (since it is ignored), as is written [here](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html):

> The use of the name `main` is important: `main` is defined to be the entry point of a Haskell program (similar to the `main` function in C), and must **have an `IO` type**, usually `IO ()`.

But you do not necessary need `do` notation. Actually [**`do` is *syntactical sugar***](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation). Your `main` is in fact:

```
main =
    putStrLn "What's your name?" >> getLine >>= \n -> putStrLn ("Hello " ++ n)
```

Or more elegantly:

```
main = putStrLn "What's your name?" >> getLine >>= putStrLn . ("Hello " ++)
```

So here we have written a `main` without `do` notation. For more about *desugaring* `do` notation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019670/desugaring-do-notation-for-monads).

Comment: In Haskell the word "monad" refers to types (like `IO`), not values (like `main`).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the entry point to a Haskell program must not be named `main` (you can change this by passing `-main-is <symbol>`) but of course that is not the focus of the question.

Comment: @user2407038 Strictly speaking, is it still a Haskell program or a not-quite-Haskell program?

Comment: The main reason to use anything other than `()` is to communicate that the program only exits either explicitly or by receiving an exception. In that case, it can an be given a polymorphic type, `IO a`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *if* you have more than one line in your `do` block, and *if* you are even using the `do` notation.

The full `do`-notation syntax also includes explicit separators -- curly braces and semicolons:

```
main = do { putStrLn "What's your name?" 
          ; name <- getLine  
          ; putStrLn ("Hello " ++ name) 
          }
```

With them, indentation plays no role other than in coding style (good indentation improves readability; explicit separators ensure code robustness, remove white-space related brittleness). So when you have only one line of IO-code, like

```
main = do { print "Hello!" }
```

there are no semicolons, no indentation to pay attention to, and the curly braces and `do` keyword itself become redundant:

```
main = print "Hello!"
```

So, no, not always. But very often it does, and uniformity in code goes a long way towards readability.

---

`do` blocks translate into monadic code, but you can view this fact as implementational detail, at first. In fact, you should. You can treat the `do` notation *axiomatically*, as an embedded language, mentally. Besides, it is that, anyway.

The simplified `do`-syntax is:

```
   do {  pattern1 <- action1
      ;  pattern2 <- action2
      .....................
      ;  return (.....)
      }
```

Each `actioni` is a Haskell value of type `M ai` for some monad `M` and some result type `ai`. Each `action` produces its own result type `ai` while *all* `action`s must belong to the *same* monad type `M`.

Each `patterni` receives the previously "computed" result from the corresponding action.

Wildcards `_` can be used to ignore it. If this is the case, the `_ <-` part can be omitted altogether.

---

"Monad" is a scary and non-informative word, but it is really nothing more than EDSL, conceptually. *Embedded* domain-specific language means that we have native Haskell values standing for (in this case) *I/O computations*. We write our *I/O* programs in this language, which become a native Haskell value(s), which we can operate upon as on any other native Haskell value -- collect them in lists, compose them into more complex computation descriptions (programs), etc.

The `main` value is one such value computed by our Haskell program. The compiler sees it, and performs the *I/O* program that it stands for, at run time.

The point to it is that we can now have a "function" `getCurrentTime` (impossible, on the face of it, in functional paradigm since it must return different results on separate invocations), because it *is not* returning the current time -- the action it describes *will* do so, when the *I/O* program it *describes* is run by the run-time system.

On the type level this is reflected by such values not having just some plain Haskell type `a`, but a parameterized type, `IO a`, "tagged" by `IO` as belonging to this special world of *I/O* programming.

See also: [Why does haskell's bind function take a function from non-monadic to monadic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118041/849891).

Comment: Actually do notation supports 3 types of statements: Bindings (the ones with <-), let statements (the ones with let without an "in") and pure monad expressions (the ones with neither). Only the last of these is permitted as the last statement.

Comment: it says "The *simplified* `do`-syntax" in the answer (emphasis added). You do not introduce something with its full specification. Sometimes best way to introduce something is with little lies even (which is also the case here because `do` works even for non-monadic values in corner cases, like `do 1`). the `do` `let` can always be rewritten as normal `let`, and the non-binding monadic value `do` statement, to a `_ <-` binding one. the answer even says "the `_ <-` part can be omitted altogether".

Comment: as for what's allowed as the last statement in a `do` block, my answer goes further and suggests always ending it with a `return ...`, as a *simplification*. which is always valid, too, thanks to the monad laws. @PaulStelian