# Why can't I call a function quicksort (randomList 10)?

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch, io-monad, do-notation

I have the following code:

```hs
import Data.Array
import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor 
import System.Random (randomRIO)

randomList 0 = return []
randomList n = do
  r  <- randomRIO (1,6)
  rs <- randomList (n-1)
  return (r:rs) 

quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

1. randomList - creates a list of a given length and populates it with random values;
2. quicksort  - quickly sorts the list.

I need to apply sorting to the created array:
`quicksort (randomList 10)`, but an error occurs:

```hs
"Couldn't match expected type‘ [a] ’with actual type IO [Int]’"
```

Comment: You should `fmap quicksort (randomList 10)`.

Comment: you should include type signatures for all top-level names in your program. if you don't know them, load the file and ask GHCi: `Main> :t randomList`. Then copy-paste it to the file (or specialize it first, as you see fit). Place the type signature above the name it describes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, 
Yes, great, it works that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include type signatures for all top-level names in your program. if you don't know them, load the file and ask GHCi: `Main> :t randomList`. Then copy-paste it to the file (or specialize it first, as you see fit). Place the type signature above the name it describes.

GHCi says

```
randomList ::
  (System.Random.Random t, Num t, Num a, Eq a) => a -> IO [t]
```

but you most probably meant

```
randomList :: (System.Random.Random t, Num t) => Int -> IO [t]
randomList 0 = return []
randomList n = do
  r  <- randomRIO (1,6)    -- randomRIO (1,6) :: IO t  , r :: t
  rs <- randomList (n-1)   --             rs :: [t]
  return (r:rs)            --    r :: t , rs :: [t]
```

In general,

```
randomRIO (1,6) :: (System.Random.Random a, Num a) => IO a
```

You cast a 6-sided die `n` times and collect the results in a list. By the way the same thing is done by

```
sequence $ replicate n (randomRIO (1,6))
===
replicateM n (randomRIO (1,6))

> :t \n -> replicateM n (randomRIO (1,6))
           :: (System.Random.Random a, Num a) => Int -> IO [a]
```

Then, GHCi also tells us that

```
 quicksort :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
```

But `randomList n` is  `IO [t]`, not `[t]`. To get to the `[t]` value living inside the `IO [t]`, you need to do it *on the inside*:

```
sortRandom :: (Ord t, Monad m) => m [t] -> m [t]
sortRandom randomlist = do
    xs <- randomlist        -- randomlist :: IO [t] , xs :: [t]
    let ys = quicksort xs
    return ys
```

The above can be abbreviated to

```
sortRandom :: (Ord t, Monad m) => m [t] -> m [t]
sortRandom = liftM quicksort     -- for monads
```

or

```
sortRandom :: (Ord t, Functor f) => f [t] -> f [t]
sortRandom = fmap quicksort      -- for functors
```

whichever you prefer. Both work with `IO` which is a monad, and any monad is also a functor. So in the end you can define

```
foo :: Int -> IO [Int]
foo n = liftM quicksort $ replicateM n (randomRIO (1,6))
```

Comment: When compiling, I get an error in this line: "randomList :: (System.Random.Random t, Num t) => Int -> IO [t]"
 Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘System.Random.Random’

Comment: do `import System` as a whole, without the `(randomRIO)`.

Comment: Can I do the following afterwards? `sort n = do`
 `list <- randomList n`
 `let res = sortRandom list`
 `return res `

Comment: no. follow the types! (that's the general slogan of Haskell). go one by one, slowly, write down the types: `randomList n :: IO [Int]`; hence, `list :: [Int]`; `sortRandom :: (Monad m) => m [Int] -> m [Int]`, or specifically for `IO`, `sortRandom :: IO [Int] -> IO [Int]`. this means it is a function that expects `IO [Int]`, not just `[Int]`. So `list :: [Int]` can't be its argument. but we have `quicksort` which can accept the `[Int]` argument, so for `let res = quicksort list`, `res :: [Int]`. and so `return res :: IO [Int]`. I'll search for a link to an explanation of `do` shortly...

Comment: @Vasiliy, if you're working in `IO`, and with randomness, you should really use a genuine quicksort instead of that fake one! The only tricky thing is that you'll have to switch from lists to arrays. Of course, if you're not dedicated to quicksort, you should almost certainly use a different algorithm instead: bottom-up mergesort is very nice in Haskell, and heapsort is all right too.

Comment: @ WillNess,
While there is no clear understanding of how this works. But you are helping me great! Thank you!

Comment: @Vasiliy I try to explain the do notation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728131/849891). also check out [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdo-notation%5D+user%3A849891) in the [tag:do-notation] tag.

Comment: @Vasiliy also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50815136/849891). so with do notation, the stuff to the right of `<-` lives in some monad `M` -- It can be `M a`,`M b` etc., but with the same `M` for every line in `do`. and if there's an `M a` type value to the right of `<-`, the value to its left has type `a`. that's the main thing. also, `do`s can be nested and unnested freely: `do { A ; B ; C } == do { A ; do {B ; C}} == do { do { A; B }; C }.  if you have a question, don't hesitate to ask.